# Corregir el código para adaptarlo a visual basic

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hola estoy intentando pasar el siguiente código de C# a Visual Basic ya que quiero aprender ambos y soy muy nuevo en ambos.
El primero sería en C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Sulakore.Communication;
using FreeHc.Properties;
using Tangine;
using Sulakore.Modules;
using Tangine.Habbo;
using Sulakore.Habbo;
using Sulakore.Protocol;




namespace FreeHc
{
    [Module("El nombre del projecto", "La descripcion del projecto")]

    public partial class Form1 : ExtensionForm
    {
        ushort inFurnitureLoad=4444;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connection.SendToServerAsync(inFurnitureLoad, 3, 11, 1, 1);
        }

    }
}
```

Lo que he intentado en visual basic pero no funciono:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Sulakore.Communication
Imports Tangine
Imports Sulakore.Modules
Imports Tangine.Habbo
Imports Sulakore.Habbo
Imports Sulakore.Protocol


Public Class Form1
    Dim u As UShort = 1444

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Connection.SendToServerAsync(u, 3, 11, 1, 1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error que me da el del visual basic:

> Error BC30451 'Connection' is not declared.

Estoy intentando traducir este mismo código a visual basic ¿Alguien me podría indicar o aconsejar como hacerlo de forma correcta?

Comment: Como ya se mencionó, una diferencia obvia es que no incluyes la herencia con `ExtensionForm`. Pero hay muchos otros detalles importantes que faltan. Por ejemplo, esto no se trata de una clase normal.  Como puedes ver en C#, es una clase parcial, de lo que parece ser un WinForms. Para implementar algo equivalente en VB.NET, debes crear un WinForms también, no solo una clase a mano.

Answer (score 2):

La única diferencia que puedo apreciar es que la clase en c# se hereda de `ExtensionForm`, y debes hacer lo mismo en Visual Basic.

Seguramente la clase `Connection` está definida en esta clase.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Sulakore.Communication
Imports Tangine
Imports Sulakore.Modules
Imports Tangine.Habbo
Imports Sulakore.Habbo
Imports Sulakore.Protocol


Public Class Form1
    Inherits ExtensionForm

    Dim u As UShort = 1444

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Connection.SendToServerAsync(u, 3, 11, 1, 1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te pueda servir un conversor

Podrías usar : http://converter.telerik.com/